# How to Add A LinearLayout Manager and GridLayout Manager in RecyclerView in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I had a design is needed to implement like a Top image on the View and bottom there is a `GridView` with two coloumns. So I am Planning to implement it Using `RecyclerView`. For top I need to use the `LinearLayoutManager` and Bottom it has `GridLayoutManager` . So How can I create a Recycler Adapter with these two values.

Comment: Use GridLayoutManager with spanSizeLookUp ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you know how to create RecyclerView adapter with multiple view types, this is how you specify the layout manager for the recyclerview

```
mAdapter = new MyMultiViewAdapter(); // an imaginary adapter that supports multiple view types

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
glm.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                switch(mAdapter.getItemViewType(position)){
                    case MyAdapter.TYPE_HEADER:
                        return 2;
                    case MyAdapter.TYPE_ITEM:
                        return 1;
                    default:
                        return -1;
                }
            }
        });

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm); 
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: What is MyAdapter Here in Case

Answer (score 4):

`RecyclerView` takes a single layout manager. Therefore, to achieve what you need you would use `GridLayoutManager`.

The span size would be set to 2, to get the two columns. Then, you would use `setSpanSizeLookup` to mark the first item as spanning both columns. Into this view you would put your "Top image".

```
public boolean isHeader(int position) {
    return position == 0;
}

GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        return isHeader(position) ? 2 : 1;
    }
 });
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

Then, the `onCreateViewHolder` can return a different view holder based on the item type at that position.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return isHeader(position) ? VIEW_TYPE_HEADER : VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_HEADER) {
        // Setup header view holder
        return new HeaderViewHolder(...);
    }
    // Setup item view holder
    return new ItemViewHolder(...)
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (isHeader(position)) {
        return;
    }
    // Bind item to the item view holder
}
```

Hope this helps!