# how to different Android multi viewholder layout manager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to use multi holder recyclerview like this image

But to do that, I have to use two layout managers of RecyclerView, Grid and Linear, but I'm not sure how to do it.
Most of the search results said no.

I would like to ask a question just in case, is this screen possible because it uses a multi-view holder? What should I do?

[image]

i found [How to Add A LinearLayout Manager and GridLayout Manager in RecyclerView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987895/how-to-add-a-linearlayout-manager-and-gridlayout-manager-in-recyclerview-in-andr)

But it seems to use a grid layout like a linear layout.

Can I implement the screen I'm talking about with this?

I saw this and tried it, but it doesn't work well....

Comment: I don't think you can use two layout manager in the same recycle view, but why don't you use more than one recycle view in the same layout and configure them at the same time ?, like you can assign a click/select listener to holders of the first recycle view and if the user clicks something in the first recycle view you change the content of the other ones and notify their adapter with data set changed

Comment: You have to make use of multi-view type to make such type of RecyclerView